# Adding javascript from code breaks the validation on page! How to handle it?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, ajaxcontroltoolkit

What I have is button that should open another page only if textbox length is 8. Javascript must be added from code because it does not simply calls the bla.aspx, it's more like bla.aspx?id=4&code=234 etc etc...

I have this code on server side

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick","javascript:window.open(bla.aspx)");
```

on client side i have

```
<asp:TextBox ID="policyNumberTxt" runat="server" MaxLength="8" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="policyNumberTxtRev" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="policyNumberTxt" ErrorMessage="Length must be 8."  
    ValidationExpression="{.{8}.}" ValidationGroup="bla" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<asp:Button ID="printBtn" CssClass="button" Text="Print" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="bla" />
```

What happens is that when I click the button page bla.aspx opens, and even postback is trigered. Validator is showing the message, but page is opened and postback trigered.

How to handle this? Validation is broken...

Thanks..

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" prefix to the "onclick" code (unless there's something dumb about ASP.Net that requires it ...)

Comment: Aslo, what validator?  What message?

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator ErrorMessage="Length must be 8."

Comment: Removing the prexif does nothing. Window is still being opened, and postback trigered.
If I add EXACTLY same button without server side script adding everything works like a charm...

Comment: ~ Also look up "OnClientClick"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/276071.aspx)

```
this.cmdSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick","if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') Page_ClientValidate();if(Page_IsValid){window.open('upload_status.aspx','_blank','width=250,height=250');}");
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent submitting the form add "return false;"

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open('bla.aspx'); return false;")
```

but that would also prevent the form from doing postback at all!

note that the passed url should be enclosed in quotes..
And you don't need the "javascript:" prefix as 'Pointy' said

I think the validation regular expression should be more strict to allow only letters and numbers like this

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Za-z0-9]{8}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the client click logic in the onsubmit of the page's form instead?

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean. I need to have client click event adding on server side.

Comment: Try something like this.Page.Form.Attributes.Add("onsubmit", your code);